# SSRS- multi value report data does not display in tablix

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

below is my stored proc.

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[Rpt_ProgramActivityReport ] 
(

 @StartDate DATETIME   ,
  @EndDate DATETIME   ,
  @RegionId varchar(25)  = NULL,
  @OrganizationId varchar(25) = NULL  ,
  @County varchar(25) = NULL,
  @ActivityId varchar(25)  = NULL,
  @InterventionId varchar(25) = NULL,
  @Status varchar(25)  = NULL,
  @StrategyId varchar(25) = NULL,
  @MethodApproachId varchar(25)  = NULL,
  @TargetPopulationId varchar(25)  = NULL,
  @PrimaryProblemId varchar(25) = NULL,
  @SecondaryProblemId varchar(25) = NULL,
  @InterveningVariableId varchar(25) = NULL,
  @FundingSourceId varchar(25)= NULL 

)

AS 

BEGIN


SELECT 
FACT.Id fActivityId, FACT.ActivityName,
ACT.fOrganizationRegion_Id ,ACT.Id AS ActivityId,ACT.CreateUserId,
(US.LastName + ',' +US.FirstName)AS UserName,
REG.Id  AS RegionId,REG.OrganizationName AS RegionName,
ORG.Id  AS OrganizationId , ORG.OrganizationName AS OrganizationName,
FC.Id AS FundingSourceId, fc.FundingSource,
CA.Id AS CoverageAreaId, CA.County , CA.ZipCode
FROM Activities ACT
JOIN fActivity FACT ON FACT.Id = ACT.fActivity_Id
JOIN fOrganizationRegion ORGREG ON ORGREG.Id = ACT.fOrganizationRegion_Id
JOIN fOrganization REG ON REG.Id = ORGREG.RegionOrg_Id
JOIN fOrganization ORG ON ORG.Id = ORGREG.Org_Id
JOIN ActivityFundingSource AFC ON AFC.Activity_Id = ACT.Id
JOIN fFundingSource FC ON FC.Id = AFC.FundingSource_Id
JOIN ActivityCoverageArea ACA ON ACA.Activity_Id = ACT.Id
JOIN fCoverageAreas CA ON CA.Id = ACA.CoverageArea_Id
JOIN Users US ON US.UserId  = ACT.CreateUserId
LEFT JOIN fInterventionType ITYPE ON ITYPE.Id = FACT.InterventionType_Id
LEFT JOIN ActivityInterveningVariable AIVAR ON AIVAR.Activity_Id = ACT.Id
LEFT JOIN fInterveningVariables IVAR ON IVAR.Id = AIVAR.fInterveningVariable_Id
LEFT JOIN ActivitySecondaryPriorityProblem ASPP ON ASPP.Activity_Id = ACT.Id
LEFT JOIN fPriorityProblem PP ON PP.Id = ASPP.fPriorityProblem_Id
LEFT JOIN fMethodApproach MA ON MA.Id = ACT.fMethodApproach_Id
LEFT JOIN fStrategyMethodApproach  SMA ON SMA.fMethodApproach_Id = MA.Id
LEFT JOIN fStrategy ST ON ST.Id = SMA.fStrategy_Id
LEFT JOIN ActivityTargetPopulation ATP ON ATP.Activity_Id = ACT.Id
LEFT JOIN fTargetPopulation TP ON TP.Id = ATP.TargetPopulation_Id


WHERE


    (Act.CreateDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
AND ( (@RegionId IS NULL) OR  REG.Id  IN( SELECT * FROM dbo.FnSplit(@RegionId ,',' )) )
AND ((@OrganizationId IS NULL) OR   ORG.Id  IN ( SELECT * FROM dbo.FnSplit( @OrganizationId ,',' )))
AND ( (@County IS NULL) OR CA.County  IN ( SELECT * FROM dbo.FnSplit( @County,',' ) ))
AND ((@ActivityId IS NULL) OR FACT.Id  IN ( SELECT * FROM dbo.FnSplit( @ActivityId ,',' ) ) )
AND ( (@FundingSourceId IS NULL) OR FC.Id  IN ( SELECT * FROM dbo.FnSplit(@FundingSourceId ,',' )) )
--AND ((@Status IS NULL) OR ACT.Completed  IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.FnSplit( @Status ,',' )))
AND ((@Status IS NULL) OR ACT.Completed  IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.FnSplit( cast(@Status as varchar) ,',' )))
AND ((@InterventionId IS NULL) OR ITYPE.Id  IN ( SELECT * FROM dbo.FnSplit( @InterventionId ,',' ) ))
AND ((@InterveningVariableId IS NULL) OR IVAR.Id  IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.FnSplit(  @InterveningVariableId ,',' )  ))
AND ((@SecondaryProblemId IS NULL) OR PP.Id  IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.FnSplit(@SecondaryProblemId  ,',' )))
AND ((@PrimaryProblemId IS NULL) OR PP.Id  IN  (SELECT * FROM dbo.FnSplit( @PrimaryProblemId ,',' )))
AND ((@MethodApproachId IS NULL) OR MA.Id  IN  ( SELECT * FROM dbo.FnSplit(@MethodApproachId ,',' ) ))
AND ((@StrategyId IS NULL) OR ST.Id  IN   ( SELECT * FROM dbo.FnSplit(@StrategyId  ,',' )))
AND ( (@TargetPopulationId IS NULL) OR TP.Id  IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.FnSplit(@TargetPopulationId,',' )))


END
```

when I run it i see data.
 also I have a report where I use the same stored proc in data set.
while I execute the data set I get the records.
but when I add the fields to the report tablix. it returns NO Records.

I Have also modified and checked the data with using the below codes in parameters in data set.

```
=Join(Parameters!RegionId.Value,",")
=Join(Parameters!OrganizationId.Value ,",")
=Join(Parameters!County.Value,",")
=Join(Parameters!ActivityId.Value,",")
=Join(Parameters!InterventionId.Value,",")
=Join(Parameters!Status.Value,",")
=Join(Parameters!StrategyId.Value,",")
=Join(Parameters!MethodApproachId.Value,",")
= Join(Parameters!TargetPopulationId.Value,",")
= Join(Parameters!PrimaryProblemId.Value,",")
= Join(Parameters!SecondaryProblemId.Value,",")
= Join(Parameters!InterveningVariableId.Value,",")
= Join(Parameters!FundingSourceId.Value,",")
```

but issue is I still get the records when i execute the data set separately . but in report tablix it does not display the data.
Can any one help me on this.??

Comment: I have to ask, how slow is that proc with all those udf calls?

Comment: its fast. and there are only 300 records in db. and it only takes less than a second to return.

Comment: Ah, because of the 300 records. But I'd caution using this methods

Comment: i guess there is no issue with stored proc , but issue is in reporting side only.

Comment: If you are running locally is vs make sure you refresh the local cache.

Comment: Also, if you are sure the data is not cached and everything else is configured then you might want to start by removing the entire WHERE clause, run it, and then each where clause back, one by one, until you find the offending statement.